# How can I use React with ES6 modules

Tags: reactjs

How can I use React with ES6 modules? The npm package contains only CJS and UMD version, which I cannot import into my ES6 code directly (I am not using babel to transpile my source).

I tried to work around by creating a dummy package which `require` the umd package and export as ES6 module, which obviously did not work since ES6 exports are static and UMD import is dynamic.

Is there any other alternative, other than building an ES6 version of React.js from source.

Comment: Use create-react-app to generate boilerplate. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: @Satyaki I think you misunderstood the question. Joyce wants to use ES6 modules without Babel and probably also without webpack, since ES6 modules are now supported by browsers directly. CRA does use both Babel and webpack.

Comment: @Satyaki That does not allow me to import CJS/UMD modules directly into my ES6 source. The `create-react-app` includes `Babel` for compiling everything to ES6.